# Invalid Operation Exception after changing from .Net 2.0 to .Net 4.0

Tags: .net, vb.net, invalidoperationexception

I am working with a project that was developed in VB using .Net 2.0. This project was never completed, but I need to make use of it to test new code. When loaded, there were several errors which were corrected by bumping the .Net version up to 4.0. (Don't ask me why... it might have been developed on a higher .Net version, and then bumped down to 2.0 to make it compatible with shared classes; the project was abandoned because of .Net incompatibility).

The problem that I am now having is when compiling and running, I get an exception before the UI comes up. about an invalid operation exception (full text listed below).

This code will not be released, so I am not concerned with stability. What I really need to do is follows what happens in debug mode when it receives a file, so i can determine why the files I am sending are being refused.

Thank you for any help.

--- Full Error Text ---

> System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled
>     Message=An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'Framework.Utility, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>     Source=HL7.Receiver
>     StackTrace:
>          at My.MyProject.MyForms.Create_*Instance*_[T](T Instance) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 190
>          at My.MyProject.MyForms.get_ReceiverForm()
>          at My.MyApplication.OnCreateMainForm() in C:\Code\Common Production Components\HL7 Receiver+Sender\HL7 Receiver\HL7 TCPIP V2\My Project\Application.Designer.vb:line 35
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
>          at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[] commandLine)
>          at My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>     InnerException: System.BadImageFormatException
>          Message=Could not load file or assembly 'Framework.Utility, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>          Source=Framework.Windows.UI
>          FileName=Framework.Utility, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>          FusionLog==== Pre-bind state information ===
>   LOG: User = User
>   LOG: DisplayName = Framework.Utility, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
>    (Fully-specified)
>   LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Code/Common Production Components/HL7 Receiver+Sender/HL7 Receiver/HL7 TCPIP V2/bin/Debug/
>   LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
>   Calling assembly : Framework.Windows.UI, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
>   LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
>   LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Code\Common Production Components\HL7 Receiver+Sender\HL7 Receiver\HL7 TCPIP V2\bin\Debug\HL7.Receiver.vshost.exe.Config
>   LOG: Using host configuration file: 
>   LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
>   LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
>   LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Code/Common Production Components/HL7 Receiver+Sender/HL7 Receiver/HL7 TCPIP V2/bin/Debug/Framework.Utility.DLL.
>   ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.

```
   StackTrace:
        at Framework.Windows.UI.Form..ctor()
        at ReceiverForm..ctor() in C:\Code\Common Production Components\HL7 Receiver+Sender\HL7 Receiver\HL7 TCPIP V2\Forms\ReceiverForm.vb:line 22
   InnerException:
```

If it helps any, here is the auto-generated code in question:

```
Namespace My

'NOTE: This file is auto-generated; do not modify it directly.  To make changes,
' or if you encounter build errors in this file, go to the Project Designer
' (go to Project Properties or double-click the My Project node in
' Solution Explorer), and make changes on the Application tab.
'
Partial Friend Class MyApplication

    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New(Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationMode.Windows)
        Me.IsSingleInstance = false
        Me.EnableVisualStyles = true
        Me.SaveMySettingsOnExit = true
        Me.ShutDownStyle = Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.ShutdownMode.AfterMainFormCloses
    End Sub

    <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()>  _
    Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()
        Me.MainForm = Global.ReceiverForm
    End Sub
End Class
```

End Namespace

Line 34, where the error is, says `Protected Overrides Sub OnCreateMainForm()`. Thanks again for any suggestions.

Comment: Relevant details from the exception: *"The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'Framework.Utility, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format"*

Comment: Project + Properties, Compile tab, Advanced Compile Options, Target CPU setting.

Comment: I suppose I should have been more specific above; sorry about that. My question would be what I could do to get Framework.Utility to load. It is a part of the project, and the dll is created. There is mention of incorrect format, which makes me think of the .Net change. Also, research online showed a possible link to updating from .Net 2.0 to 4.0. I tried changing the .Net to 3.5 for all projects, but this created several more errors. I do know that Framework.Utility is being used with other software running under .Net 2.0. Again, thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Thank you Hans, I tried this. I am stuck with one option: Any CPU.

Comment: Goto Build --> Configuration Manager, in the Active Solution platform select Add New then add the other Platforms (x86 and x64) that should give you the option to do as Hans suggested

Comment: Thank you Mark. I was not aware that I could do that. Adding x86 changed all projects in the solution to run on x86. Since this is not going to production, I don't care much what it runs on. When building this time, the application worked. So thanks go to both Mark and Hans. Not quite sure how to give you credit for it, though.